# Truncate From CSV, but Not From Insert

Tags: mysql

When attempting to import a csv, I receive a truncation error on my float column. However if I test with a single Insert statement, it works, even though the value is the same. How can I identify what is different even though all the values appear identical between the insert and the import.

Table constructed as

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
user_id varchar(32) not null,
name varchar(32) not null,
review_count int,
yelping_since date,
useful int,
funny int,
cool int,
fans int,
average_stars float,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
```

Import SQL (produces truncation error)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/limitedusers.csv'
INTO TABLE Users
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

The CSV contains only a single row of data:

[image]

EDIT: Error text = Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'average_stars' at row 1

This insert statement works just fine though:

```
INSERT INTO Users
VALUES ('B8FKS2jjTZ7xneWuadrH4w','Daniel',12,'2013-03-11',2,0,0,0,2.38);
```

Comment: Perhaps would be useful if you can add the error details to the question.

Comment: @AbidSulemanAhmed error added in edit

Comment: In the image of your CSV file it doesn't look like fields are terminated by a comma.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson How can you determine that?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the csv has some invisible characters which causes error.

To test it, create a table with average_stars as varchar(20) and see check the value of the column.